# How Long Should A Variable Be Stored In A Register?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, cpu-registers, register-allocation

Register is the most powerful place to store and process data in Assembly Coding, however, it has a limited space compare to the main memory. Therefore, I think that determine when to move a data to a register and when to move it out is very important for optimizing the assembly code, especially when a lot of register usage is required.

So, **How long should a data be stored in a register before moving it into the main memory for later on use(after processing in the register)**? Or do I just put them in the memory when no more register are there for me to process a new data? (Personally I don't think this is appropriate:P)

Consider the following code (1st Code):

```
MOV EBX,SomeAddressForLaterUse
;...-imagine 37 lines of assembly code here
MOV ESI,SomeAddress
MOV EDI,EBX
MOV ECX,SIZE_IN_BYTES
REP MOVSB
```

Now Consider this other code (2nd Code);

```
MOV EBX,SomeAddressForLaterUse
PUSH EBX
;...-imagine 37 lines of assembly code here
MOV ESI,SomeAddress
POP EDI
MOV ECX,SIZE_IN_BYTES
REP MOVSB
```

Above, I think it's pretty obvious that the second code has advantage for saving one more register to use in those 37 lines of assembly code (unless this 37 lines of assembly code doesn't use many registers), but sometimes it's very confused to choose between these two methods, for instance, what if it was 10 lines of code instead of 37?

All in all, is there some sort of rules when determine moving data away from a register?

Comment: You gave a rule and said you don't like it.  Can you point to anything bad about that rule, any specific times it gives bad results?  Once you find a specific problem with that rule, you have a basis for improving on it.

Comment: Not sure your question has an easy answer, but one thing to note: accessing most processors' L1 cache can usually be done in less than a clock cycle, so you could think of that entire space as registers. So that's typically 32k or more on a modern CPU. Also, issues like algorithm selection, cache-awarenss etc. usually dwarf any gains you'll get from micro-optimizing at the instruction level. What type of project is this for?

Comment: @QuadrupleA: Sure, but the CPU is trying to retire multiple instructions during that single clock cycle, and it's not possible for all of them to perform L1 cache access.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: On a pipelined CPU couldn't only one instruction be in the 'memory fetch' stage at a time anyway? I would think latency would be the same whether the instruction made a memory fetch or not (as long as it wasn't a cache miss).

Comment: @QuadrupleA: The pipeline is multiple micro-ops wide.  Modern pipelines aren't so simple as 'this stage is for memory fetch', either.  Have a look at https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/haswell#Pipeline and http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf  For simplicity's sake, let me just point out that instruction fusion only allows one of the two instructions to have a memory access, so if you put a register spill adjacent to another instruction that needs to access L1, you'll prevent fusion and reduce throughput.

Comment: Specifically in your example if you put `MOV EDI,SomeAddressForLaterUse` somewhere among the last lines of that "37 line of code", when edi is already unused, it will be as fast as `MOV EDI,EBX`. Push/pop is accessing stack memory, that will be slower. The only better option is to have that `SomeAddressForLaterUse` in `EDI` since start trough whole code (not using EBX at all). Giving CPU some space between load of value to register, and first usage of register, will help performance. So in your second example that load of ebx + push ebx after it hurts. REP MOVS after ecx/esi/edi load hurts.

Comment: So you shouldn't be bothered how long some value stays in register after usage, but you should focus how long before usage it is loaded ahead - to give CPU some room to do other things while the value is on it's way to the register (especially from memory it may take some time). The more ahead you are capable to prepare the register values, the less stalls you will hit. Whether you use few more additional `mov` instructions to prepare data for processing loop doesn't matter, you have billions of instructions per second, when not stalled/depending on something. BTW, modern CPU may+will reorder.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at this completely backwards.  The rule for when something gets spilled to memory really is as simple as "when you run out of registers".

The complicated part is deciding *which register to reuse*.

Once you decide that, you identify two key points in the code -- the last use of that register for its old purpose, and the first use for the new purpose.  The spill can happen at any point between those, and here you'd take into account processor characteristics, what other instructions are being executed that require memory accesses, how long the dependency chain is in calculating the final value -- and eventually come up with the optimal time to perform the spill to avoid a pipeline stall waiting for the memory controller.

Add to that the calling convention considerations such as which registers which must be preserved by called functions and which are considered scratch space, and in many cases a leaf function won't need to do any spills to memory at all.

On some architectures, processor characteristics vary widely enough that the information needed for optimization isn't available when ordering the instruction stream.  (x86 is a good example).  In such cases, the CPU itself may have an out-of-order execution engine with a significant amount of logic dedicated to reordering instructions (or the micro-ops they are split into) in a way that's optimal for the particular microarchitecture.  This execution-time optimization can also take into account branch prediction statistics, something that ahead-of-time compilation can only do if profiling traces have been collected.

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to do is to compute/place values in registers, and ideally never, ever move them to memory ("spill") which is "far away" and thus slow to access.

The way this is handled by many compilers is to start by assuming that *every* computed value is in a register at some point in the code. That requires an infinite (well, unbounded) number of registers, which is clearly more than the machine has so it can't really work.   Yes, you might have 10,000 values in registers at some point in time for really big program.  (Even more!)

But, if you could decide which of those unbounded ones were the least important, you could force them to spill/be in memory, and now you have fewer registers containing values.   If you spill enough, you get to the point where what is left will fit in the real registers.

This is accomplished by what is called a [graph-coloring algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).  The idea is that you build a graph, whose nodes are values-in-some-register at a point in the code, and arcs which connect nodes where the values must be live at the same time; these are called "interference arcs".

What the coloring algorithm does is to decorate the nodes with colors (well, register numbers).   Imagine your machine has 8 registers, and you want to have the variable X in some register; there's a node in the graph that represents this.

There's a two phase process to do this hueristically.  Phase one chooses nodes that can clearly be colored, by virtue of having fewer neighbors than there are registers, and resolves the case where a node has more neighbors than registers.  The second phase assigns colors/registers.

- Phase 1: Repeat until graph is empty: pick a node with with fewer neighbors than actual registers; remove it (and its arcs) from the graph and push onto a stack. If no choices left, pick a node with too many neighbors [often it is good to pick the node with the largest number of neighbors], delete from the graph, push onto the stack [Such a node *may* have its register spilled to memory by Phase 2].
- Phase 2: Repeat until stack is empty:  Pop a node from the stack and add it and its arcs back to the graph.  If possible, assign a color/register to that node, that is not any of the colors/registers of it neighbors; this is the actual register that value will use.  (This step will sometimes succeed in coloring a node that might otherwise have to be spilled) If one cannot pick such a color/register, then this node cannot be allocated to a register without one of it or its neighbors being spilled; we solve this problem by assigning an arbitrary register to this node to be used for its computation, and a memory location somewhere to hold its computed value while its neighboring nodes are computed.

Viola, you've assigned a register number to every value in a way that spills only a few registers in practice.  [This document gives more detailed explanation and basic algorithm](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/temp/register-allocation.pdf).

No, you don't want to do this by hand, but it is easy to build a procedure to do this.

[This paper discusses how to revise this scheme to handle messy ("irregular") architectures like the x86 where the registers are not all equivalent](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~feeley/cours/ift6232/doc/pres2/generalized-graph-colloring-register-allocator.pdf).